# Running a raw sqlite query

Tags: android, sqlite

I am  trying to run this query but it just isn't working and i can't seem to find what is wrong with it.

```
public boolean verifyUser(String name , String pword){
   boolean result = false;
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   try {   
   Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from user where username="+name+" and password="+pword+"", null );

      int count = res.getCount(); 

      res.moveToFirst();
      if (count == 0) 
      {
          result = false;
      }
      else{
        result = true;
      }
   }
      catch (SQLiteException se ) {
          Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not log in");
      }
      return result;
      //return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, you need to put your string literals in `'single quotes'`. Better yet, use parameters:

```
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from user where username=? and password=?",
    new String[] { name, pword } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the following query

```
select * from user where username='"+name+"' and password='"+pword+"'"
```

actually you are missing the **Single Quotes**

Comment: This will blow up when a value contains a quote.

Comment: Tried this but somehow my program is still crashing. Is there a way I can see what is going on in my database through command prompt? I am using eclipse

Comment: @CL kindly clarify please

Comment: Any quote will end the string; the following characters are interpreted as an SQL expression. With luck, you will get a syntax error; in the worst case, you have an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @CL I am using this approach in my all applications, fortunately , I haven't came across any such conflict. ...may be helpful if you refer to some resource, any way the other answer given by laalto is having the same approach, but he is passing arguments in some different way...

Answer (score 0):

Checked this, it's edited of your code.

```
public boolean verifyUser(String name , String pword){
   boolean result = false;
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   try {   
   Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from user where username='"+name+"' and password='"+pword+"'", null );

      int count = res.getCount(); 

      //res.moveToFirst(); //Remove this line (It may be crashing because of this line.)
      if (count == 0) 
      {
          result = false;
      }
      else{
       res.moveToFirst();
        result = true;
      }
   }
      catch (SQLiteException se ) {
          Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not log in");
      }
      return result;
      //return true;
   }
```